# "replaceAll()" en java no funciona correctamente

Tags: java

Buenas,

Estoy usando una pequeña línea de código para limpiar la información de precios obtenida a través de "scrap". Dado que obtengo de distintos países, tengo distintas monedas y quiero dejar el número limpio.

Para ello uso:

```
price.select("span").first().text().replace(".", "").replaceAll("SG$|CAD|R$|HUF|€|₽|incl. GST|$|R|₹|£|¥|₩|NT$","")
```

¿Cuál es el problema? Pues que hay 3 caracteres que no me quita: $, SG$ (moneda de singapur) y NT$ (Moneda de Taiwan).

Tal cuál está podría entender que la moneda de Taiwan no funcionase bien puesto que antes de sustituir NT$ está la sustitución del dólar ($), entiendo que debería quedarme entonces NT. Sin embargo no pasa ni una cosa ni la otra.

No acabo de encontrar el problema, el resto de caracteres sí que los quita.

Comment: Veo en tu perfil que tienes casi todas tus preguntas con respuestas sin aceptar, algunas preguntas incluso duplicadas. Te recomiendo que revises todas tus publicaciones y agradezcas el esfuerzo por ayudarte de los usuarios que se han molestado en darte una solución, o que les respondas si no lo han conseguido, pero no sigas haciendo preguntas sin "cerrar" de alguna forma las que tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,

La solución finalmente ha sido esta:

```
price.select("s").first().text().replace(".", "").replaceAll("SG\\$|CAD|R\\$|HUF|€|₽|incl. GST|NT\\$|R|₹|£|¥|₩|\\$",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que los caracteres especiales como $ en html se representan con un código y no literal

Así el equivalente de $ es `&#36;`

entonces cambia tu replace incluyendo el código y no el literal.

Es lo que se me ocurre que podría ser

Aqui hay una tabla con caracteres especiales http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: No he entendido bien el que $ es $.

Comment: @JetLagFox No me fije que me interpreto el código pero ya actualice la respuesta

Comment: He probado con esto pero no me funciona: `price.select(".price-disclaimer span").first().ownText().replace(",", ".").replaceAll("SG&#36|CAD|R&#36|HUF|€|₽|incl. GST|NT&#36|R|₹|£|¥|₩|&#36","")`

Comment: te falto incluir el ";" punto y coma es parte del código

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, prueba a poner antes del '$' la barra invertida '\', así por ejemplo:

```
replaceAll("SG$|CAD|R$|HUF|€|₽|incl. GST|$|R|₹|£|¥|₩|NT$","")
```

Comment: Yo no veo ninguna barra invertida.

Comment: Te refieres a `SG\$` o a `NT\$`... Tu respuesta no lo deja muy claro.

Comment: Eso no compila porque no reconoce `\$` como una secuencia de escape. La forma es envolverlo entre corchetes `[$]` para que lo trate como un carácter como he puesto en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
La cadena que quieres reemplazar tiene varios problemas, se podría quizá solucionar con un regex pero... por ejemplo, a parte del problema con el signo de $, le pides que te reemplace los puntos y dentro de las monedas tienes un valor con punto (.).

Entonces, te planteo esta solución. Funciona creando una cadena imaginaria:

```
public class Reemplazar
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    /* CADENA IMAGINARIA: 
     * Para tu código usa esta variable:
     * String sSinMoneda=price.select("span").first().text(); 
     * La de abajo es para probar el programa
     */

    String sSinMoneda="SG$100. $1000 SG$1000 200NT$ 1CAD 50HUF 20€ ₽456 incl. GST 6875 R45 ₹67 £658 ¥89 ₩234 NT$142";

    //Este valor tiene un punto (.) por lo tanto reemplazamos antes que reemplazar el . sólo
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replace("incl. GST", "");
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replace(".", "");
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replaceAll("CAD|HUF|€|₽|incl. GST|R|₹|£|¥|₩","");
    //Todos los reemplazos con el signo $
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replace("SG$","");
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replace("R$","");
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replace("NT$","");

    //Dejamos a $ sólo para el final
    sSinMoneda = sSinMoneda.replace("$","");

    System.out.println(sSinMoneda);
  }
}
```

**Resultado**

> 100 1000 1000 200 1 50 20 456  6875 45 67 658 89 234 142

Answer (score -1):

Tu problema es que quieres usar como caracteres a los que representan otras cosas ([ver documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):
    1.- El carácter **.** representa cualquier carácter (por eso se ve que lo pusiste aparte, pero lo puedes incluir en la regexp)
    2.-El carácter **$** representa un final de línea

Para marcar un carácter en concreto envuélvelo entre corchetes []. Si cambias tu expresión regular por la del código que te pego te debe funcionar (incluye también el punto y te ahorras otro `replace`):

```
String ejemplo = "SG$100. $1000 SG$1000 200NT$ 1CAD 50HUF 20€ ₽456 incl. GST 6875 R45 ₹67 £658 ¥89 ₩234 NT$142";
ejemplo = ejemplo.replaceAll("SG[$]|CAD|R[$]|HUF|€|₽|incl. GST|[$]|R|₹|£|¥|₩|NT[$]|[.]","");
System.out.println(ejemplo);
```

Con esto la salida es:

> 100 1000 1000 200 1 50 20 456  6875 45 67 658 89 234 142